# How to split an inhomogeneous dataset into several files according to some specific keywords in the dataset?

Tags: python

I have a `.dat` file that shows results of a lab experiment at different conditions (you can find the dataset [**`here`**](https://www.kaggle.com/abdelrahmanyoussef94/lab-experiment-data)). The data file is inhomogeneous, meaning that the number of rows and columns differ from one place to another, just as follows:

[image]

The dataset has also Table 2, Table 3, .. , Table 7.

So, what i need to do is to split this dataset into multiple files according to each table of records, i have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

f = open('BCZT015Fe_21-120.dat', 'r')

databaseRaw = f.read()

database = databaseRaw.split('Table ')

f.close()

for i in range(0, len(database) - 1) :
    database[i] = 'Table  '+''.join(database[i])

for i in range(0, len(database)) :
    f = open("output" + str(i) + "" + ".csv" ,"w")
    f.writelines(database[i])
    f.close()
os.remove("output0.csv")
os.remove("output1.csv")
os.remove("output2.csv")
```

My idea here is trying to save the data in a list, and iterate over the whole database and whenever the word "table" is detected, I just split the data before and after. The problem with this approach is that the resulting files have the data stored into just one column (which is understandable since i am saving the dataset in just one list), so, how can i split such a dataset into multiple files and keep the data from the original file as it is in the separated files?

Hope someone could help me out with this problem, and Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be preferable if your example data was text rather than an image so we could test solutions.

Comment: @DarryIG i just uploaded the dataset on Kaggle and put the link in the question
https://www.kaggle.com/abdelrahmanyoussef94/lab-experiment-data

Comment: Table 1 is mentioned twice.  Also, a lot of the data is name-value pairs rather than a table.  Regardless of this, do you just want to split the data into separate files?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanYoussef--any clarification to my comment above?

Comment: @DarrylG Yes, exactly! Table 1 is mentioned twice and i want to split both of them in separate files. and the main aim i am trying to achieve is to split every single set of data after the "Table 1, Table 1, Table 2, etc.) into separate files and keeping the data as they are in the original file (i.e. after the explanations of the conditions before each table the data should still be stored into columns as in the original file).

Comment: @AbdelrahmanYoussef--still a bit confusing since even the data between rows of "Table XX" is non-homogeneous i.e. containing a mixture of name/value pairs and table data.  Also, some of the name/value pairs have more than one ':' such as `Waveform: D:/Measurements/Ahmed/Bipolar_100Hz.tfw : Bipolar 100Hz`.